# Image analysis for loop

Tags: python, image, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to create a for loop that will produce the size (width, height) of each image (as arrays). Here is my code:

```
def arrayDesiredImages(folder, ratnumber, follicletype):

    # join folder path, rat number, and follicle type 
    directory = os.path.join(folder, ratnumber, follicletype)
    # iterate through files in this joined directory, directory
    image = []
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file:
            # to display images in this given directory
            # join the image file name with the directory's path        
            myimage = rgb2gray(imread(os.path.join(directory, file), plugin = "matplotlib"))
            image.append(myimage)
    return image

rat_list = [93, 94, 100, 103, 105, 106, 108, 110, 111]

type_list = ["Cysts", "GF", "Follicles"]

path = r"C:\Users\blake\Box\Histology"

rat_c_total = []

rat_g_total = []

rat_f_total = []

for i in range(len(rat_list)):

    rat_c = arrayDesiredImages(path, "rat"+str(rat_list[i]), "Cysts")

    rat_c_total += rat_c

    rat_g = arrayDesiredImages(path, "rat"+str(rat_list[i]), "GF")

    rat_g_total += rat_g

    rat_f = arrayDesiredImages(path, "rat"+str(rat_list[i]), "Follicles")

    rat_f_total += rat_f


def shape(fname):
    
    for i in range(len(rat_c_total), 1):
        size_c = rat_c_total[i].shape
    for i in range(len(rat_g_total), 1):
        size_g = rat_g_total[i].shape
    for i in range(len(rat_f_total), 1):
        size_f = rat_f_total[i].shape
    return shape


print(rat_c_total[42].shape)

shape(size_c)
```

Results:

> (324, 276)
>
> <function **main**.shape(fname)>

- I want my code to produce an answer for each image like the one above. But I keep getting `<function__main__.shape(fname)>` Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Dont just post all your code. Post only relevant part, (the part containing hte error) pls.

Comment: but im guessing you forget () somewhere. it should be `rint(rat_c_total[42].shape())` instead of `rint(rat_c_total[42].shape)`.

Comment: but please edit your question so it wil follow counity standards.

Comment: @Urh I don't think that's the case; he references `shape` as an attribute several times elsewhere. Also, it's a function, not a method of a class, and needs an argument.

Comment: @themadpsychologist  yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `shape` as an attribute, but then redefine it as a function. You'll need to rename either the `.shape` attribute or the `shape()` function to use your code.